# Making application ask for Save before logoff/shutdown as done for notepad/word/excel etc

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

## Problem

I have an WPF/MVVM application that used Prism. When the user makes some changes and has some unsaved stuff in the application. Then with this unsaved changes the users logs off or shutdowns the application

When this happens, I want the application to halt the logoff/shutdown and ask the user for a Save.

*For a WinForm application I think using a FormClosing event solves the problem. What is the solution for a WPF application?*

I am working on a couple of solutions and will post them tomorrow. By that time any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I use Prism's CompositePresentationEvent for this. The Shell publishes the event when it wants to close and the view model that may wish to ask for save changes and cancel the close, subscribes to the event

```
public class ApplicationClosingEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<CancelEventArgs> { }
```

In the Shell.xaml.cs. The _eventAggregator is an IEventAggregator:

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ApplicationClosingEvent>().Publish(e);

    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

In the vm constructor:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<ApplicationClosingEvent>().Subscribe(OnApplicationClosing);
```

In the vm, OnApplicationClosing runs when the Shell wants to close:

```
private void OnApplicationClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Ask user to save changes, e.g. In a message box 

    switch (result)
    {
        case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
            // Save changes
            break;
        case MessageBoxResult.No:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to this solution, you could verify if any change is still unsaved before raising the **MessageBox** with for example an ***AllChangesSaved*** flag, which you would update after editing or saving the information. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use the [Window.Closing event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a more useful answer by elaborating a little? Maybe provide an example for the user? I'd like to invite you to read the [Answering help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the *Provide context for links* section.